# Faking LISP-like closures in Python?

Tags: python, closures, lisp

Apologies for the unhelpful title, but I don't know how to phrase my question in a catchy one-liner. Let me therefore explain it.

In languages like Common Lisp you can use closures to "hide global variables", as in

```
(let ((my-global-variable '(foo bar))))
   (defun f (x) (append my-global-variable x)))
```

The desired effect of this is that

1. You get a variable accessible within your function that **persists between function calls**
2. that is **invisible outside the scope of your function**

where 'invisible' should be taken with a grain of salt since it may still be possible to access the variable from outside using implementation-dependent inspection facilities. Let us therefore agree that 'invisible' means 'does not affect the global namespace of variable'.

One possible way to achieve 1. and 2. in Python is via:

```
def helper_function():
    my_global_variable = ['foo', 'bar']
    def f(x):
        return my_global_variable + x
    return f
f = helper_function()
```

Evaluating `f(['baz'])` returns `['foo', 'bar', 'baz']` as expected, and it satisfies 1. and 2. However in contrast to the Lisp version, it is not true that

3. the variable is **mutable/rebindable** within the function

depending on whether your using Python <= 2 (no) or Python 3 (yes). Since my intent is to store in this variable a computationally expensive object, mutability is not important.
But apart from that the above solution suffers from other problems.

More precisely, **I ask whether there is another solution** that

4. is **less verbose**
5. and **does not pollute the name space** with helper objects (`helper_function` in the above example)

?

Below is a list of answers, compiled out of the helpful comments from [user2357112](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2357112/user2357112), [CircArgs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7907717/circargs), and [Stefan Pochmann](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1672429/stefan-pochmann).

**Solution 1: Callable Object** (satisfies 1-3)

```
class helper_class:
    my_global_var = ['foo','bar']
    def __call__(self, x):
        return self.my_global_var + x
f = helper_class()
```

**Solution 2: Default Values to Optional Arguments** (satisfies 1,2,4,5 (or 2,3,4,5; see below))

```
def f(x, my_global_var=['foo', 'bar']):
    return my_global_var+x
```

Note that the variable *is mutable*, but mutations do not carry over between function calls, so it does not satisfy 1 and 3 simultaneously. Note also that the default argument is only evaluated once (when the function is defined), so it is acceptable for my purposes.

**Solution 3: Function Attributes** (satisfies 1-5)

```
def f(x):
    return f.my_global_var + x
f.my_global_var = ['foo', 'bar']
```

Technically this is the best solution (at is satisfies all requirements), but it is slightly more verbose than using default arguments.

**Solution 4: Clever Namespace Hack** (satisfies 1,2,5)

```
def f():
    my_global_var = ['foo', 'bar']
    def f(x):
        return my_global_var + x
    return f
f = f()
```

Note that the `f` being returned is really the inner and *not* the outer one.

Comment: It does what I want; I checked it.

Comment: Perhaps you can provide a more explicit example? I too am leaning towards your Python code not actually being what you want.

Comment: Define a class, or *maybe* use function attributes. Trying to use closure variables for this is awkward in Python.

Comment: @StefanPochmann The code defines a callable function (`f`). I checked that it is callable as if it'd been defined simply using `def`. The line `my_global_variable = []` introduces a variable binding that results in a closure when the 'internal' `f` is returned.

Comment: @StefanPochmann The point is that the variable `my_global_variable` is only visible from within the function `f`. This is why closures are so useful.

Comment: You should really familiarize yourself with Python on its own terms before trying to turn it into Lisp. `my_global_variable = []` doesn't matter because `my_global_variable = x` creates a *completely different* variable rather than using the one from the outer scope, and `my_global_variable = x` doesn't matter either because there's no way to access the value of any of these variables and no way for their value to have any effect on anything. Also, `defun` isn't a thing in Python, so it doesn't look like you actually ran this.

Comment: @user2357112 The variable is visible from within the inner function because a closure is created. My first example contained an error though, because "clojured" variables are read-only in Python (but that's enough for me).

Comment: @TomKarzes The example has changed, there are no assignments in the inner function anymore. And yes, it tested it.

Comment: The essence of what has been said is that Python is lexically scoped. Your "helper function" won't do what you want here. Try to make a closure in python behave as an iterator using `return`. You'll find that if Python were lexically scoped having the functional closures like a purely functional language all would work as you expect. Instead, there is `yield`. Containing state like you would expect in a dynamic scoped language like Lua is best handled with Python Classes

Comment: @CircArgs I want to have a constant object that is only visible from within the the function I define. The above code defines a function `f` in which the (immutable) variable `my_global_var` is visible. That is what I want. The only thing that's bothering me is that I need to define another function to achieve that.

Comment: @BlenderBender Python "closures" are the wrong way to go about that. Use encapsulation of objects and a `__call__` method. Just to be clear about what I am getting at about the way Python is with such scoping I'll provide a simple example that will possibly surprise you if you are expecting things to work as if this were purely functional:

Comment: `code='''def f():
    i=0
    def g():
        i+=1
        return i
    return g


iter=f()

iter()'''` run exec(code) the result will be `UnboundLocalError`

Comment: @CircArgs Callable objects seem to essentially be what I want. Would you mind making that into an answer?

Comment: @CircArgs The error is because you are *assigning* to the variable `i`, but the variable `i` is immutable. Please evaluate my example in your interpreter to see that it works.

Comment: A much simpler way to do what your example does is simply `def f(x): return ['foo', 'bar'] + x`. Why not just do that?

Comment: @StefanPochmann Because the computation to be done by my real-world-f is actually way more expensive than that.

Comment: @BlenderBender So? I don't see the problem with that...

Comment: Maybe `def f(x, prefix=['foo', 'bar']): return prefix + x` then?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156229/discussion-between-blenderbender-and-stefan-pochmann).

Comment: @StefanPochmann using an optional variable actually seems like the least verbose solution, even if it's still not ideal.

Comment: @BlenderBender You could do `f = (lambda prefix=['foo', 'bar']: lambda x: prefix + x)()`, that doesn't have the optional parameter. Or you could just use your original and finish with `del helper_function` to clean up the name space.

Comment: @StefanPochmann Afaik, a lambda expressions in python must be one-liners. For such a simple `f` this approach might be okay, but for more complicated functions it wouldn't work. Deleting the helper function would help with cleanliness, it would also make it even more verbose. I think optional arguments are the best way to go.

Comment: @BlenderBender Depends on what you mean with "one-liner" and "work" :-). Anyway, just one more option: `def f(x): return f.prefix + x` followed by `f.prefix = ['foo', 'bar']`.

Comment: @BlenderBender Yet another: Call your helper function `f` instead of `helper_function`. Then the `f = f()` overwrites the helper so you don't need an extra `del`.

Comment: @StefanPochmann Didn't know about function attributes, that's handy to know. I think optional arguments and function attributes are both best worksarounds, each having different flaws. Optional arguments may lead to hard-to-detect bugs if you are forgetful and treat it like a closure and assign something to it. The flaw with function attributes is that they *are* visible from the outside (if you insist to look). Still, both are very acceptable solutions.

Comment: I see you added a few solutions to your question. I think you'd better post them as an *answer* instead.

Comment: *closures in Python aren't mutable.*: that's not true. If the closed-over variable is a mutable object, it's mutability isn't altered by having been closed over. If you mean that you can't rebind a closure, then that's no longer true in Python 3.

Comment: All this fuss over editing, *way* too many comments, and still there is no clear question here. ***What problem are you trying to solve, why do you think you even need this***? Python is not a language where you try to hide data and structures.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes, I meant non-rebindability. What is it you do not understand? I give a very simple example of how you can use a let expression and closures in Lisp, in order to have a variable that persists between function calls but is only visible from within this function, and I ask for a way to get this behaviour in Python. *Why* I want this is irrelevant.

Comment: It is *very relevant*, because you are wasting energy on this; you are going against the Python grain here. Note that Python closures are still introspectable, for example, so you can never actually reach your visibility constraints.

Comment: But if you perhaps explained what you are trying to achieve we can suggest different solutions.

Comment: @MartijnPieters "It is very relevant, because you are wasting energy on this": I don't even know what this is supposed to mean. I just explained to you what I want in my previous post. Other people have already suggested solutions to this problem, which are quite acceptable. I can reword my question to make it a little clearer, but I don't understand the fight you are fighting here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Closures can also be inspected in Lisp; I'm perfectly okay with this limited invisibility.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I have made some effort to make my question clearer and more readable. Please review these changes and unhold the question if you think the question is clear now, so that I can move the list of solutions to an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are looking for something of the sort. I think it is more pythonic than trying to wrestle with Python to get purely functional behavior:

```
class Helper:

    __hidden_var=5

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def __call__(self, x):
        self.__hidden_var=x
```

I've been a bit arbitrary as I'm not entirely sure what you want, but I've demonstrated a callable object as you requested. Note that the `__` have made the attribute inaccessible outside an instance once an instance is instantiated (although this isn't **totally** true as you can still get it with instance._Helper__hidden_var). You might choose to use something like your helper function to truly hide such a variable. You could easily implement another method to edit the hidden variable [encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming))

Comment: If they dislike having `helper_function`, I think they'll hate having `Helper`. Does it have any advantage? To me it just seems *worse*.

Comment: @StefanPochmann I suppose in a sense he asked for a demo of how a callable object would be used to emulated a lexical closure. I think this is cleaner though. Certainly is clearer what is going on at a glance.